# Floating not right in ie?

Tags: css, xhtml

i want to do like the following format:

[image]

So this is what i did :

```
<style>
.toptitle{
 font-size:14px;
}
.toprating{
background:yellow;
float:left;
font-size:12px;
}
.topcontainer{
border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
</style>

<div class="topcontainer">
<div class="toprating">256</div>
<div class="toptitle">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="topcontainer">
<div class="toprating">256</div>
<div class="toptitle">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

Now, in firefox,chrome,safari, this works perfectly, but in IE the title goes about 30 px down.

Is there a mistake in the code, or is there any better code to do this?

Comment: Never look at what IE does and consider your markup a mistake when the other far more modern browsers show what you wrote. IE is the worst browser on the planet.

Comment: "Never look at what IE does", bad advice. Look, but **don't care *much***. If you can fix it easily, then try that. If it takes more than 5 days, then skip the problem (and possibly create two layouts: one that works for IE, other for other browsers, and use server-sided scripting to determine which layout to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE you'll need to float the title as well like this:

```
.toptitle{
  font-size:14px;
  float: left;
}
```

Alternatively, if the rating is a constant width, just give it space like this:

```
.toptitle{
  font-size:14px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.toprating{
  background:yellow;
  float:left;
  font-size:12px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: @Tom - I'm not seeing that here in IE7/8, which version of IE, and what other CSS do you have?

Comment: IE8 & thanks ;) fixed by doing like this !!
      <div class="topcontainer">
      <div><div class="toprating">256</div></div>
      <div class="toptitle">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
      <div class="clear"/>
      </div>

Answer (score 1):

You need to float topTitle and clear.

```
<style>
.toptitle{
  font-size:14px;
  float: left;
}
.toprating{
  background:yellow;
  float:left;
  font-size:12px;
}
.topcontainer{
  border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
} 
</style>

<div class="topcontainer">
  <div class="toprating">256</div>
  <div class="toptitle">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
  <div class="clear"/>
</div>
<br>
<div class="topcontainer">
  <div class="toprating">256</div>
  <div class="toptitle">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
  <div class="clear"/>
</div>
```